# Cannot install WAS application, yet cant find application on unix server

Tags: unix, websphere

The error I get is: "Application already exists in the configuration repository."

So I did a google search and ALL of the results uniformly tell me to go to my unix box and delete the files that match the application name. We tried restarting the unix server, and the WAS8.5 admin console. Still, I can't find any instances of this application in ANY of the directories suggested to look:

profiles//blas
profiles//cus
.. etc

I even did a file search on the whole system and no results appeared:
"find / -name '*APPLICATION*' 2>/dev/null"

The only other relevant piece of information is that I installed this application (seemingly successfully) about a month ago, yet there are no logs of that installation and once again, no instances of this application name appears on the file system, so there are no traces of it.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The application files are located at `[PROFILE_ROOT]/config/cells/[CELL_NAME]/applications`, `[PROFILE_ROOT]/config/cells/[CELL_NAME]/blas` and `[PROFILE_ROOT]/config/cells/[CELL_NAME]/cus`. Can you confirm that these are the directories you checked?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I meant, but somehow the formatting was messed up. I checked: /WebSphere/AppServer85/profiles/*PROFILE*/config/cells/*CELL*/applications, blas, cus

Comment: If you have a Network Deployment (ND) environment, you should be looking in the DMGR profile for the application directory. Try manually syncing all the Nodes using the syncNode command.